# WaitOnAddress unresolved

Tags: c++, c, windows

Using MSVC 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

The .cpp file has `#include <windows.h>`

The VC++ include path in the project properties is `$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);`.  That is the default installation and hasn't been tampered with.

The program uses several WINAPI functions and compiles without errors,
but if I rebuild the program (ReleasUnicode/Win32), I receive a link error:

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WaitOnAddress@16

All other WinAPI functions get resolved.

After hours of trail and error, I found that manually adding the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x86\synchronization.lib to the project resolves this error.  On the other hand, instead adding its path, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x86`, to the VC++ include directories doesn't solve the error.

Why does this error occur?  I think I have correctly included the library path and the header file, and all other WinAPI calls work fine.

Comment: what is the windows version?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise Eval Version 10.0.14393

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx) says that you must link to **synchronization.lib** (See the *Requirements* section).

Normally you would just add synchronization.lib to the list of libraries  to link to in **Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies**.

Most of the winapi functions are available through kernel32.lib, user32.lib and other libraries which are linked in by default, but these APIs needs you to explictly link to synchronization.lib

Note that this is different from header files, which you #include in your source code, header files contains declarations, while .lib files contains the implementation you link into your application, or the .lib file points to a .dll file that the application will load at runtime.

Comment: From that particular MSDN page I got the hint towards synchronization.lib, but I cannot read that it says that I shall explictly link to it. It's different than other WinAPI calls behavior at link time is unexpectable to me.

Comment: The documentation doesn't spell out explicitly every thing you need to do, it simply states you must : include Windows.h (or SyncAPI.h), and link to synchronization.lib - from this you are required and expected to inspect your settings, and link to synchronization.lib if its not already done. (Regardless of using Visual Studio or something else)

Comment: @jamacoe - "It's different than other WinAPI calls behavior " - of course no. for any WinAPI you must include some lib as linker input

Comment: Only the most commonly used libraries are typically included by default, depending on your choice of build tools.  As soon as you use any part of the API that is off the beaten trail, so to speak, you'll need to explicitly specify the relevant library.  Other examples include the process management API and the modern ACL management API.